# Is it possible for Red Rocket Truck Stop to get raided?

Tags: fallout-4

I can't afford Home Plate in Diamond City, so Red Rocket Truck Stop seems like the next best thing. Is it possible for Red Rocket to get attacked by raiders? I have another character that put tons of stuff in the workbench in Red Rocket and it was always there (but then again I have 4 turrets guarding it). I have no settlers there, nothing of any interest except for the workbench loot and T-45 power armor, will it be safe?

Comment: Like the answer below, I have been attacked by Super Mutants and Raiders at Red Rocket, even with no settlers.  All my stuff is still there.  But, if you are looking for a settlement that won't be attacked, get Hangman's Alley. It's also more central than Red Rocket, and every X weeks some Super Mutants spawn to the South and get into fights with Diamond City guards, so you can easily pick up some ammo or other junk.

Comment: @nailbones Hangman's Alley can be attacked. I've been attacked by raiders. They spawned in the large open alley area outside the gate, to the northeast.

Comment: @DCShannon I think I had raiders attack me once as well, but I thought it was just a random wandering party, not an actual raid.  Either way, as Hangman's alley has its entry points already walled with a doorway, it's trivial to place a few turrets inside and take down attackers as they come through the chokepoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for any of your settlements to be attacked by raiders (or super mutants, rust devils, etc). From personal experience, neither Red Rocket nor Sanctuary have ever notified me that they were being attacked and that I needed to defend them, but Red Rocket has been attacked at least once every three times I stop by there.

[Here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/164592-fallout-4/72820144?page=1) is a thread where people are talking about their Red Rocket being attacked.

> Had three raiders try to ambush me around the time my first Red Rocket settler was assigned to the gardens.... I offed them pretty quick though.
>
> My settlement or base is the red rocket station and I get attacked regurarly, almost always by super mutants and some times raiders. Have like +80 defense orso.

I haven't had a time where it notified me that my Red Rocket settlement was being attacked and that I needed to defend it, though. Not sure if it's because I send every single companion to Red Rocket or not.

Comment: I don't think I've been notified, but there have been plenty of times where I was at Red Rocket Truck Stop and raiders/robots came and attacked. It's my main base as well.

Comment: Pretty sure Nelson is right that you need a settler at the location for it to be attacked. Saw the formulas before, and this was part of it.

Comment: What people do see for empty settlements is that enemies spawn near it.  It's not a real attack because there is no quest, but that random dude seeing you makes it feel like you were "attacked".  Settlement attacks are scaled to your level.  Meeting a random plain Raider when you're level 100 isn't an attack.  Seeing 3 Raider Veterans in Power Armor, along with a quest marker, is.

Answer (score 1):

## Your Red Rocket Truck Stop won't be raided.

The key is the lack of settlers.  Any settlement without settlers will never be attacked.  You don't need any defenses there except to help you when you visit it.

On survival, I deliberately make some settlements empty to achieve this because I cannot fast travel, don't want to run back out here after setting up a Provisioner, and just don't feel like building an area up.  It sometimes involve killing existing settlers, but that's life.

Comment: It sounds like the asker is concerned about stuff being stolen from their workbench when an attack happens. I don't think that's possible anyway, is it? They just wreck things like crops and turrets.

Comment: Actually, enemies CAN steal stuff out of your containers.  I've had a Raider steal an Exploding Assault Rifle and all its bullets from the box.  The trick is to make sure bullets and weapon are not in the same container.  They can also take from the shared workshop inventory.

Comment: @Nelson why would you store weightless bullets in the first place though

Comment: Survival is for real men.

Comment: Wait, are you saying if you DON'T play Survival, ammo is weightless? Wow, talk about making things easy. Limitless rockets fit into your gear? haha. I should try the lower settings @Vemonus

Comment: @Crossfit_and_Beer that's exactly what that means.  Non-survival difficult has weightless bullets.

Comment: This includes Nukes.

Answer (score 0):

"Raided" as in attacked by raiders? Yes! Any of your settlements can be attacked.

If you mean "raided" as in looted by the enemy then Yes/No. For you to fail to defend your settlement, you would have to have a very very poor defense.

But nonetheless, if you happen to fail, the ramifications aren't all that harsh really. You would of course lose all the dead settlers, some or all food crops and water in the workbench, and you would need to rapair stuff like turrent and the such. Your loot would remain as is, though.

To prevent defeat, set up some turrets on top of the building to boost your defense. This number must be higher than your food + water. Meeting that requirement will keep prevent raids from happening as far as I have observed.

Coincidentally, I tend to send all my companions to Red Rocket, since its a small, easy-to-fortify location and it makes it easy to find my followers, while keeping them out of sight in my main settlement. I tend to pimp my followers with my secondhand (still really good) weapons and armor, remember to give them ammo, though. That gives me some peace of mind for additional protection in case any invaders were to get past the turrets. But, that's me being paranoid. Them getting past the turrets with the appropriate defenses has never happened.

An extra tip: Don't leave fusion cores in your unused power armor frames. Settlers and companions will hijack them when your settlements get attacked. Most times you can tell them to get out, but remeber that Bethesda has a lot of bug and there as several reported cases of this being a big issue.